# iphone development: table view returns empty table

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am brand new to iOS development, and I could not find a solution on here or Google, so I'm asking out of desperation.

I have a class "ViewController" that is a subclass of UIViewController.  In here, I have:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([self.bookTitle.text length] > 0)
        self.entries = [self.bookLibrary searchForBook:self.bookTitle.text];

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString: @"BookList"]) {
        TableViewController *controller = (TableViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.itemCounter = [self.entries count];
        controller.bookLibrary = [self.entries allValues];
    }
}
```

The view for this on the Storyboard has a connection to a Table View Controller that I dragged and dropped onto the grid.  I clicked the "Table View Controller" at the bottom, and set my custom class "TableViewController" in the custom class input box.

Now, from what I understand, the method above is passing all the data properly to the TableViewController.

Here's one of the methods I have in the TableViewController

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"BookCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    Book* book =  [self.bookLibrary objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = book.title;
    NSLog(@"%@", book.title);
    return cell;
```

}

The NSLog entry is printing out all the book titles to the console, so I know for a fact the data is being passed.  However, when I run the program and click the button to pull up the Table View, it's just an empty table.  Any hints?  I can upload my entire project.  Been at this for several hours and a bit frustrated.  Please help :(

EDIT: A response suggested I look at the state of my data variables in the table methods.  It suggests their state is not what I think it is and that I should use NSLog to print out their values.  I did just that, and I can see all the values printed out.  I don't understand... they do infact have values assigned to them.  The problem isn't that the data is missing.

Comment: Have you updated the `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` function. With the number of cells to be displayed.

Comment: Yes I have.  I have set it to return 1.

Comment: Also, it may be just a typo but you've said that you have a ViewController class that's a subclass of UIViewController. However, if you're going to assign this class to a UITableViewController you dragged out, then it has to be a subclass of UITableViewController to match. If it's not, your class isn't going to get hooked up to the UITableView properly.

Comment: The two ways to do a UITable in your storyboard are (a) drag out a UITableViewController and make your custom class a subclass of UITableViewController; this causes automatic "hook up" of the UITableView to your class as the delegate and data provider. (b) drag out a normal UIViewController and manually add a UITableView to it, and make your VC class a UIViewController; here, you're then going to have to manually hook up your VC class as the delegate and data source for the UITableView to get those delegate method calls sent from the table to your VC.

Comment: Here's a link to my project.  I just zipped it up as I'm relatively new to Stack Overflow (and programming in general).
http://www.filedropper.com/googleapitest_1

Bill - I have two controllers.  "ViewController" for the initial screen of my app, and "TableViewController".  The idea is the user enters a book title on the initial screen and presses the button.  This triggers a call to a Google web service which returns with JSON data.  I want to show that data on the table view.

Comment: to clarify, "ViewController" is a subclass of UIViewController and "TableViewController" is a subclass of UITableViewController.

Comment: You said you are returning **1** from `numberOfRows`, you should return the number of books you have.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're either using a UITableViewController subclass as your VC (if you're using a UITableViewController ui object from the pallet), or that you're properly hooking up the UITableView's delegate and datasource properties to your VC (if you're using a plain UIViewController object and subclass).

(see comments on question).

Try this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"bookLibrary.count %d", bookLibrary.count);
    return [bookLibrary count];
}
```

You'll find that things are not what you think they are... Add in an implementation of `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` along with that, each with their own "I'm here" NSLog statement, and trace the flow of that second view controller appearing. Again, you'll find you've got some sequencing issues where the flow isn't working quite the way you might be assuming.

---

Added comment:

Ultimately, the origin of your problem is this line in your "sending" controller's prepare for segue method:

```
controller.bookLibrary = [self.entries allValues];
```

What is this doing? It's calling `allValues` on the Dictionary object. That method generates a new array (!) containing the values. You don't store that new Array object in any permanent storage. You just use it to set:

```
controller.bookLibrary = ...
```

So, right after that statement executes, you have:

- an Array object in your prepareForSegue method (where the code is executing) that you've only stored in one variable/holder, which is:
- a *weak* pointer to that object over in your destination view controller (TableViewController)

The method ends.

The Array returned by `[... allValues]` is not being held on to by anything in the Source view controller, so the only thing holding it from being garbage collected is the pointer to it in the Destination view controller.

But that pointer is a *weak* pointer. By definition, if that's the only pointer to an object, the pointer will be set to nil and the object released for garbage collection. *Poof!*  No more array object, and you're left holding a nil pointer.

As you discovered, setting the "receiver" to *strong* lets it hold on to that Array object, even after the other code exits and it's the only pointer to the Array.

(And, your code isn't being invoked twice. If you look closely at the logging -- or better yet set a breakpoint inside the table get-row-count method -- you'll see it's only being called once. The earlier logging of "I have 8 objects" is happening over in other code, not in your TableViewController.)

Comment: First of all, thank you for very fast response!  Secondly, I am doing already.

Comment: Took a look at your project, and you've got a mix of issues. Put some NSLog statements in your table method and you'll see that your data, when those methods are running, is not what you think it is... Print out the state of your data at every point where you're making assumptions about what data "should exist in which vars right now" and you'll find the stat isn't what you think it is. :-)

Comment: Thank you again for the response.  So the problem is with the data and not with how the TableViewController file is associated with the Table View object on the storyboard?

Comment: I'm trying to think hard on what you're saying.
     - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        NSLog(@"There are %i books in the library.", [bookLibrary count]);
        return [bookLibrary count];
    }
The log prints 7.  In addition, the tableView:cellforRowAtIndexPath: log statement also prints out the book titles.  Where do I need to log the data?

Comment: Btw.. the string I entered when I ran it was "hobbit" for the search.

Comment: I needed to declare my bookLibrary property in the TableView class as strong instead of weak.  

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        NSLog(@"There are %i entries in the book array.", [bookLibrary count]);
        return [bookLibrary count];
    }

This log statement was printing twice in the console.  The first time it would have the correct number and the second statement would have 0.

Comment: I still don't quite understand why making it from weak to strong fixes this... I mean, I understand the difference between the two somewhat, but at what point does the program lose the initial value of the array?  Like when does it get lost?  At what point?  Is the Table View Controller loaded twice?

Comment: See expanded answer.  Added comment there.

Comment: And feel free to accept the answer here in SO if it sounds correct to you. :-)